# Как найти элемент по названию класса в selenium c#?

Tags: c#, selenium

Есть класс со следующим именем: "_postpost page_block post--withPostBottomAction post--with-likes deep_active".
Как можно найти элементы с таким классом на странице, если выдается ошибка: Compound class names not allowed. Cannot have whitespace in class name.
Все говорят использовать XPath. Есть ли решение без использования Xpath?

```
<div id="post-103083994_3958581" class="_post post page_block post--withPostBottomAction  post--with-likes deep_active" data-post-id="-103083994_3958581" onclick="wall.postClick('-103083994_3958581', event);" data-replies-limit="1" post_view_hash="c8430e7d826fa686cc">
  <div class="_post_content">
```

Comment: Можно использовать еще CSS селекторы. `By.CssSelector("._postpost.page_block.post--withPostBottomAction.post--with-likes.deep_active")` Для меня они выглядят немного дружелюбнее XPath.

Comment: `Как можно найти элементы с таким классом` это не класс, а список классов. Классы разделены пробелами.

Comment: @aepot, ну хорошо, в коде элемента страницы увидел `class = "_postpost page_block post--withPostBottomAction post--with-likes deep_active". `
Как мне тогда производить поиск? Через css selector тоже не работает, выдает:  
`Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"._postpost.page_block.post--withPostBottomAction.post--with-likes.deep_active"}`

Comment: Покажите точный html код и точный c# код в вопросе. И ошибку туда тоже скопируйте. Чтобы в угадайку не играть. Дополните пост.

Comment: @aepot, Я указал ошибку в вопросе, а также объяснил, что хочу. Точный html код будет очень огромным, потому что берется из раздела новостей из соц. сети вк

Comment: Ох, еще одна душа полезла в селениум, думая, что это решение всех проблем... Вы хоть себе задавали вопрос: зачем мне целый браузер в проекте? Касательно "без XPath" - есть, обходите все дерево, пытаясь найти нужный объект сами, но зачем? Это не знаю, как кататься на лыжах, только лыжи будут из бревен, кривые, зато сделаны вами. Лучше не избегайте, а изучайте, мой вам совет. Касательно поиска - советую искать не по всем классам, а по одному или нескольким, ведь часть может постоянно меняться, а лучше вовсе по ID. И да, когда задаете вопрос, кидайте не классы, а участок HTML с нужными данными.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, во-первых, я не считаю, что это решение всех проблем, но мне нужно сделать через селениум. Во-вторых, я задал вопрос, в котором конкретно спросил, можно ли реализовать без XPath. Если такого решения нет, вы можете просто сказать, а не приводить свои сравнения. К тому же поиск по id не получится (исходя из моей задачи), так как у каждой новости свой уникальный id.

Comment: @PavelGarbuzov Понимаете ли в чем дело, я здесь не для того, чтоб решать костыли, я здесь для того, чтоб учиться, а также делиться правильными знаниями с другими. Почти каждый, кто задает здесь вопрос по парсингу сайтов, пытается решить задачу на Selenium, на вопрос "почему?", ответ почти всегда "Ну а что, можно иначе?", а когда им рассказываешь, что это делается простой отправкой запросов, в пару строк кода, они очень сильно удивляются. Не воспринимайте это как критику, воспринимайте все сказанное мной как совет. Тоже самое касается и xPath, вы отказываетесь от очень полезного инструмента.

Comment: Вы изначально показали неверный список классов `ByCssSelector("._post.post.page_block.post--withPostBottomAction.post--with-likes.deep_active")` вот так получится, но я бы на вашем месте выкинул бы точно лишние классы. Возьмите из списка минимум, чтобы просто получить нужный результат.

Comment: @PavelGarbuzov Касательно Id - то, что он динамичный, это нормально. А вот классы... Вот вы кликнули, у вас было `class = "post"`, а стало `class = "post-open"`, а вы в коде прописали всю эту портянку целиком, в итоге не находит. Id в этом плане всегда статичны, они не меняются через JS или что-то подобное, по этому мой вам совет, ищите первым делом через них. Как? Да все по сути просто `//div[starts-with(@id, 'post-')]` (или нечто такое), либо `contains` и поиск по нужному слову. Но хочу кстати заметить, постов обычно несколько на странице, лучше искать элемент в котором они находятся сначала

Comment: @aepot, согласен, мой косяк. Теперь работает, спасибо.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, я вас понял. Спасибо за советы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Селениум не работает с computed/Compound properties (в даном частном случае - "Compound class") - т.е. если в проперти class указано много классов через пробел.

Поэтому НЕ НУЖНО пытаться искать по всему полю указанному в классе. Нужно искать или ПО ОДНОМУ ИЗ УКАЗАННЫХ класcов (например только по `post--withPostBottomAction` или любому иному) или...

реализовать костыль который фиксит этот недостаток у селениума что бы  он начал работать с computed properties.

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath(".//span[contains(@class,'list-item')] AND [contains(@class,'list-item-station')]"));
```

можно написать такую функцию которая генерит подобный икспас. Тогда сможешь искать что необходимо в том числе по computed properties.

Вся магия в автоматическом преобразовании строки с классом

`_post post page_block post--withPostBottomAction  post--with-likes deep_active`

в строку

`[contains(@class,'_post')] AND [contains(@class,'page_block')] AND [contains(@class,'post--withPostBottomAction')] AND [contains(@class,'post--with-likes')] AND [contains(@class,'deep_active')]`

тогда сможешь использовать икспас и на Compound class-ах.

ничего сложного в этом нет.

---

> Все говорят использовать XPath. Есть ли решение без использования Xpath?

Есть.

- id
- name
- link_text
- css selector

и др. способами которые можно указать в методе `driver.FindElement(By.......)`

---

Но вообще родным способом для селениума было бы просто указывать икспас через путь. Не обязательно полный. То есть что-то вроде:

```
.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[@data-marker='items']/div/div/../span[@class='post--withPostBottomAction']")
```

Это правильный официально закрепленный способ использовать Xpath в селениуме.

Answer (score 0):

не надо изобретать велосипед, добавьте по By.CssSelector
и вообще здесь очень подробно всё написано, чем Вы можете пользоваться https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html